# Hide when clicked on document except when clicked on a div

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a div when clicked on a document but I dont want to hide that div when someone clicks in it or clicks a link or a button in it. Also, I have some links inside that div set to prevent the click action (return false;) and send a ajax request.

I tried:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
      $('#bubble').hide();
});

$('#bubble').click(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

It works fine but the links and buttons under the #bubble doesn't work.

Comment: why not working? http://jsbin.com/uwane

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `return false;` use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) like this:

```
$('#bubble').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This stops the `click` event from bubbling up to `document` like you want, but won't kill the event dead in its tracks like `return false;` will.  All you need to do in this case is prevent the [default bubbling behavior](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), this does *only* that :)